# Wordpress Rest Api categories serialization in kotlin data class

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, wordpress-rest-api, data-class

I have project with android app that fetch post from wordpress rest api
some field that i take is like this list.

```
[
  {
    "id": 43600,
    "date": "2020-09-07T19:52:47",
    "title": {
      "rendered": "Video: .... "
    },
    "content": {
      "rendered": "<div class=\"wp-block-embed__wrapper\"></div>",
      "protected": false
    },
    "author": 31,
    "featured_media": 43601,
    "categories": [
      788,
      2760
    ]
  }
]
```

Already read :

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room

[How to parse data of WordPress REST API using Retrofit and GSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60746596/how-to-parse-data-of-wordpress-rest-api-using-retrofit-and-gson)

[Wordpress API - How to loop through a JSON Array of objects in Android/Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45286036/wordpress-api-how-to-loop-through-a-json-array-of-objects-in-android-java)

[Android Kotlin parsing nested JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54120451/android-kotlin-parsing-nested-json)

[Parse Json to Primative Array Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49763331/parse-json-to-primative-array-kotlin)

the closest answer but mostly in converter

[Android Room Database: How to handle Arraylist in an Entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44986626/android-room-database-how-to-handle-arraylist-in-an-entity)

https://medium.com/@gilesjeremydev/room-through-a-complete-example-ce5c9ed417ba

I tried to save it into local storage with room in single entity. But based on google doc, it would seperate into 2 entities tied with annotation @relation

```
@Entity(tableName = "post")
data class SomePost(

    @PrimaryKey
    @field:SerializedName("id")
    val id: Int,
    @field:SerializedName("date")
    val date: String,
    @Embedded
    @field:SerializedName("title")
    val title: PostTitle,
    @Embedded
    @field:SerializedName("content")
    val content: PostContent,

    @field:SerializedName("featured_media")
    val imageId: Int,
    @field:SerializedName("author")
    val author: Int

)

@Entity
data class PostCategories(

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int,
    @field:SerializedName("categories")
    val postCategories: Int

)

data class SomePostRelationship (
    @Embedded
    var post: SomePost? = null,

    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "id",
        entityColumn = "categories"
    )
    var categories: List<PostCategories>? = null
)

interface PostService {

    companion object {
        const val ENDPOINT = "https://example.com/wp-json/"
    }

    // Posts
    @GET("wp/v2/posts/")
    suspend fun getPostAll(
        @Query("page") page: Int? = null,
        @Query("per_page") perPage: Int? = null,
        @Query("search") search: String? = null,
        @Query("order") order: String? = null
    ): Response<List<somePost>>
```

The problem is data class PostCategories.

**My question is how to serialization json array into entity data class of categories for android room.**

if there already answer or same question hope can link to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After tried some variation.

I decided to used converter and combine it in on dataclass for now.

```
@Entity(tableName = "post")
data class SomePost(

...

    @field:SerializedName("categories")
    var categories: ArrayList<Int>? = null,
...
)


class Converters {

...
    @TypeConverter
    fun listToInt(value: ArrayList<Int>?): String? {
        return Gson().toJson(value)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun intToList(value: String?): ArrayList<Int>? {
        val type = object : TypeToken<ArrayList<Int>?>() {}.type
        return Gson().fromJson(value, type)
    }

}
```